# Expressions do Angular JS não funciona?? Não aparece o valor 10 e o Work? aparece com chaves. Help!

Tags: angularjs, angular

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{5+5}}</p>
    <p>{{ Work? }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Já tentei de tudo! Vi se o link do src já estava atualizado e funcionando, tentei mudar com module e interpolate.Provider, as vezes ele funciona e parece que do nada para de funcionar. Por favor, se alguém tiver alguma ideia, avise. Valeu, abraço!

Comment: O que é `Work?`? isso vai dar erro se não estiver definido

Comment: errei ali kkkk era pra ser uma string depois

Comment: @LucasNiehuesdeFarias não modifique as respostas para acrescentar conteúdo. Se for adicionar conteúdo o faça na própria pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Retire o `?` do `<p>{{ Work? }}</p>`, ele está causando o erro:

```
Error: "[$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$parse/ueoe?p0=Work%3F"
    Angular 42
angular.js:15567:15
```

Para mais informações do erro veja o link acima.

Retirando o símbolo de interrogação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dica: Sempre quando trabalhar com qualquer coisa em javascript, seja ele puro, com biblioteca ou framework abra o developer tool do navegador e deixe na aba console, ali você vai ver todos os erros e ou avisos, eu achei o seu problema em 5 segundos por ter o costume de deixar o developer tool aberto quando trabalho com javascript.

Exemplo do firefox:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então eu mudei, mas agora ele dá outro erro no console. Eu sou iniciante, então pode ser que seja algo simples. Vou editar acima com o novo problema. Obrigado!

Comment: Você declarou "Work" em algum lugar, na controller, no context? Senão vai dar erro